# Correct way to iterate this data and render section headers and items?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

my JSON response looks like this 
[image]

I would like to render the name i.e. pasta/pizza as header(which can be collapsed or opened) and the items i.e. types of pizza/pasta inside the respective category.
I am using react native, I tried using map and ListView

```
return (this.props.item.items.map((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return (
      <View>
          <View style={CardContainer}>
            <Text>{res.title}</Text>
            <Image
            source={{ uri: res.photo }}
            style={imageStyle}
            />
          </View>
      </View>
    );
  })
);
```

but they return single objects so when I associate a onPress event over the category i.e. pasta it is registered twice which is undesirable as a click would mean expanding that category i.e. pasta.

Please let me know If i should change the JSON structure to make it efficient, this is a JSON response for menu card

EDIT: I tried the following but cannot get it to display result

```
renderItem() {
return (
<View>
{
  this.props.menu.map(({ name, items }) => {
      <View>
        <Text>{name}</Text>
      </View>
    items.map((resp) => {
      <View>
        <Text>{resp.title}</Text>
      </View>
    });
  })
}
</View>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<View>
  {this.props.item.items.map((res) => (
      <View>
        <Header>
          { res.name }
        </Header>
        { res.items.map(item => (
          <View style={CardContainer}>
            <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            <Image
            source={{ uri: item.photo }}
            style={imageStyle}
            />
          </View>
        )}
      </View>
    )))}
</View>
```

IMO, a little more readable

```
render() {
  const { item: { items: allItems } } = this.props;
  return (
    <View>
      { allItems.map(({ name, items }) => (
        <Header>{ name }</Header>
        { items.map(({ title, photo }) => (
           <View style={CardContainer}>
             <Text>{title}</Text>
             <Image
               source={{ uri: photo }}
               style={imageStyle}
             />
           </View>
        )}
      )}
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: I tried the following but cannot get it to display .                   
                                                                                            
 renderItem() {
  return (
    <View>
    {
      this.props.menu.map(({ name, items }) => {
          <View>
            <Text>{name}</Text>
          </View>
        items.map((resp) => {
          <View>
            <Text>{resp.title}</Text>
          </View>
        });
      })
    }
    </View>
  );
  }